# why show NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have install a fresh copy of laravel 4.2

When i visite home route (localhost/public/) it work fine but when i visit other route as like "localhost/public/kk" it show NotFoundHttpException.

here is my route.php file

```
<?php

   Route::get('/',function(){
     return View::make('hello');
   });


   Route::get('/kk',function(){
     return View::make('hello');
   });
```

here is .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
     Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

  # Handle Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: And if you try: `/localhost/public/kk` - not found as well?

Comment: actually it will be kk not demo but the result is same not found.Except home route whatever i use it show notfoundhttpexception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry point for all requests to a Laravel application is the public/index.php, therefore it would be available here --> [localhost/public/index.php/kk](http://localhost/public/index.php/kk)

for further info you can go to this [link](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/lifecycle#lifecycle-overview).

Comment: yes it is but i don't want "index.php" on the url.I have other projects those are work fine

Comment: Assuming you are using Apache, You would need to configure virtual host for that you can go to this link for further info.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: thank you shahzaib ali khan that's really helpfull.But i use xamp & win8

Answer (score -1):

First check if you have enabled the `mod_rewrite` module.
Then.. according to the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2#pretty-urls) you should try an alternative `.htaccess` if the `.htaccess` that ships with Laravel does not work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Edit: [Enable mod_rewrite in xampp](http://www.leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp/)

Comment: i have other laravel projects on this machine those are work fine but i face this problem on this fresh install project